# Python - Syntax error with nested iterations?

Tags: python, for-loop, syntax, nested, syntax-error

SO I have this code:

```
Chars = maketrans(" ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-.,"," ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-.,");

input = input.split(" ");
length = len(input);
charLength = len(Chars);
    for x in range(1,length):
            for y in range(1,charLength):
                for z in range(MinInt,MaxInt):
                    if Transform(z + x.translate(Chars) + Key)[:5] == input[x]
                        print x.translate(Chars)
```

The function receives blocks of 5 characters separated by spaces. When attempting to run it, I get the following error:

```
File "SH25.py", line 21
if Transform(z + x.translate(Chars) + Key) == input[x]
                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm admittedly a newbie at Python, but could anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is pretty precise: you need a `:` after `if`

```
if Transform(z + x.translate(Chars) + Key)[:5] == input[x]:
```